# $gH\subset Hg$ implies $gH=Hg$

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H<G$. Let $g\in G$ such that $gH\subset Hg$. Prove that $gH=Hg$.

I know that for any group $G$ (finite of infinite), if for all $g\in G$, $g^{-1}Hg\subset H$ then $gH=Hg$. But here, $G$ is finite and $gHg^{-1}\subset H$ is true only for this particular $g$. Any hints?

Comment: $G$ is finite, so you can use cardinality as an argument here. What's the cardinality of $gH$ ?

Comment: $|gH|=|H|=|Hg|$. I still don't get how to get the result from that :(

Comment: if a set is contained in another set, and the cardinaility is equal what can you say ?

Comment: What about this? $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$ and $gHg^{-1}\subset H$ implies that $gHg^{-1}=H$

Comment: But how do we know $|gHg^{-1}|=|H|$?

Comment: $|gH|=|Hg|$ and the one is inside the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $|gH|=|Hg|$. Since $G$ is finite $gH$ and $Hg$ are also finite. Now, $gH\subset Hg$ implies that $gH=Hg$.